# Computing symbolic surface normal of a surface point on a semialgebraic set

Tags: symbolic, computational-geometry

Consider a semialgebraic set; such as `reg` below:

```
With[{reg = 
   x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1 && x^2 y^2 z^2 <= 1/1000 && -x - y + z <= 0},
 RegionPlot3D[ImplicitRegion[reg, {x, y, z}], PlotPoints -> 200]]
```

[image]

My rather simple problem is: how to compute symbolic surface normal for every point (defined as `{x, y, z}`) on its' surface?

My attempts have been based on `CylindricalDecomposition` and using `Reduce` and `Solve` to compute solution for one surface coordinate as a function of two others, applying `D` accordingly, and stitching the results together. I find these constructs inelegant and Frankensteinian, and doubt their robustness. Are there nicer ways to do this?

Comment: If $(x,y,z)$ is a point on the surface $f(x,y,z)=0$, then the surface normal at $(x,y,z)$ is $\nabla f(x,y,z)/\|\nabla f(x,y,z)\|$. So you just have to decide which of your three conditions is active at $(x,y,z)$ and use its normalized gradient.

Comment: @Rahul True... the real question in this case is about mechanisation of computing this normal for an arbitrary, semialgebraic set definition (that would be good input for `CylindricalDecomposition`) such as `reg`.